# Material Design Device Compatible DIV slide in (JS/JQuery/CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fluid-layout, material-design

What I am looking for to achieve is this: [Desired Live Website](http://www.materialup.com/)

1. The feature where on clicking the div. the slide in comes in from the Right, loads the external page inside it and on close(ignore the arrow button), shuts it down.
2. The Slider Div is Device Compatible. that is, on Webpages, it fills half the screen, on Mobile screens, it fills the screen accordingly.(Screenshot attached for reference)

Now,

I have somewhat accomplished the number one pointer where the Div slides in & loads the external Page.
[***Fiddle Demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/o54ox4cp/3/embedded/result/)

```
$('#left').on('click',function(){
$('#frame').animate({left:'8'});
`});
$('#close').on('click',function(){
$('#frame').animate({left:'-100%'});});`
```

***JS for Loading of the external page***
`showIframe = function (url) {
document.getElementById('iframetarget').src = url;
document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'block';}`

What i am stuck on is how to accomplished the Pointer 2, where the slide in Div should be **Device compatible.** 
Here is Full Code Fiddle: [**Full Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o54ox4cp/4/)
fill free to direct me to a new structure in the CSS also for the Fluid width for the slide in.

 Any help would be much appreciated

[image: Webpage Screenshot] 
[image: Mobile Device Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a media query for #frame

```
@media (max-device-width : 480px) {
    #frame {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Above triggers the class when the screen size is below or equals to 480px. This can be changed to whatever width size you feel.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `max-width` in css.

```
width: 100%
max-width: 500px;
```